# How to "nest" the inclusion of modules when using the Ruby on Rails ActiveSupport::Concern feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, include, nested

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and the Ruby on Rails v3.2.2 gem. I would like to "nest" the inclusion of modules given I am using the RoR [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) feature, but I have a doubt where I should state the `include` method. That is, I have the following:

```
module MyModuleA
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # include MyModuleB

  included do
    # include MyModuleB
  end
end
```

*Should* I state `include MyModuleB` in the "body" / "context" / "scope" of `MyModuleA` or I should state that in the `included do ... end` block? *What is the difference and what I should expect from that?*

Comment: Beware that this is not a good practice at all. You may get into spurious dependencies between the order of inclusion of the modules.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you include `MyModuleB` in the "body" of `MyModuleA`, then it is the module itself that is extended with B's functionality. If you include it in the `included` block, then it is included on the class that mixes in `MyModuleA`.

That is:

```
module MyModuleA
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include MyModuleB
end
```

produces something like:

```
MyModuleA.send :include, MyModuleB
class Foo
  include MyModuleA
end
```

while

```
module MyModuleA
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    include MyModuleB
  end
end
```

produces something like:

```
class Foo
  include MyModuleA
  include MyModuleB
end
```

The reason for this is that `ActiveSupport::Concern::included` is analogous to:

```
def MyModuleA
  def self.included(klass, &block)
    klass.instance_eval(&block)
  end
end
```

The code in the `included` block is run in the context of the including class, rather than the context of the module. Thus, if MyModuleB needs access to the class it's being mixed-in to, then you'd want to run it in the `included` block. Otherwise, it's effectively the same thing.

By means of demonstration:

```
module A
  def self.included(other)
    other.send :include, B
  end
end

module B
  def self.included(other)
    puts "B was included on #{other.inspect}"
  end
end

module C
  include B
end

class Foo
  include A
end

# Output:
# B was included on C
# B was included on Foo
```

Comment: Thank you. I opened a [new related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110749/how-to-make-methods-added-by-the-inclusion-of-a-nested-module-to-be-instance) on methods.

Comment: This comment made my day: _The code in the included block is run in the context of the including class, rather than the context of the module_ . The concern itself does not have the methods that are being included. The explanation on the implicit `instance_eval` clarifies a lot where the problem comes from when you chain concerns via `included` blocks.