# How to make methods added to a class by including "nested" modules to be instance methods of that class when using the ActiveSupport::Concern feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, module, nested

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and the Ruby on Rails v3.2.2 gem. After my previous question on [how to “nest” the inclusion of modules when using the Ruby on Rails ActiveSupport::Concern feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110306/how-to-nest-the-inclusion-of-modules-when-using-the-ruby-on-rails-activesuppor), I would like to understand where I should state methods added to a class by including "nested" modules in order to make these *instance methods* of that class. That is, I have the following:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModuleA
end

module MyModuleA
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include MyModuleB
  end
end

module MyModuleB
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # def my_method
    #   ...
    # end
  end

  # def my_method
  #   ...
  # end
end
```

*Should* I state `def my_method ... end` in the "body" / "context" / "scope" of `MyModuleB` or I should state that in the `included do ... end` block? *What is the difference and what I should expect from that?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Methods in modules that get mixed into a class become instance methods on that class. While putting them in the `included` block would likely work, there's no need to do it. This, by extension, works with modules, since you can include `ModuleB` in `ModuleA` and all its instance methods become instance methods on `ModuleA`, and once `ModuleA` is included on class `Foo`, all its instance methods (including those mixed in from `B`) become instance methods on Foo.

A "traditional" mix-in looks like this:

```
module Mixin
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.send :extend, ClassMethods
    klass.some_class_method
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def some_class_method
      puts "I am a class method on #{self.inspect}"
    end
  end

  def some_instance_method
    puts "I am an instance method on #{self.inspect}"
  end
end

class Foo
  include Mixin
end

Foo.new.some_instance_method

# Output:
# I am a class method on Foo
# I am an instance method on #<Foo:0x00000002b337e0>
```

ActiveSupport::Concern just pretties this up a bit by automatically including a module named `ClassMethods` and by running the `included` block in the context of the including class, so the equivalent is:

```
module Mixin
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    some_class_method
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def some_class_method
      puts "I am a class method on #{self.inspect}"
    end
  end

  def some_instance_method
    puts "I am an instance method on #{self.inspect}"
  end
end

class Foo
  include Mixin
end

Foo.new.some_instance_method

# Output:
# I am a class method on Foo
# I am an instance method on #<Foo:0x000000034d7cd8>
```